# VC++ and MapPoint OCX control dialog issue

Tags: visual-c++, mappoint

I am writing a VC++ MFC dialog based app which requires Microsoft MapPoint embedding in it. To do this I'm using MS VC++ .NET 2003 and MapPoint Europe 2006 to do this but am having problems as when I select "Insert ActiveX Control" no MapPoint control appears in the list of options. I have tried manually registering `mappointcontrol.ocx` with `regsvr32` which appears to succeed but still the control doesn't appear on the list.

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong here, and any possible solutions.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the ActiveX control test container?  Is it in the list of controls?  How about using the register button in the test container?

Also check the registry to see if it is registered.  You should have an entry in HKEY-CLASSES-ROOT\controlName that has a CLSID element that points to a UUID.  That UUID should also be in HKEY-CLASSES-ROOT\CLSID\uuid and have a LocalServer32 entry that points to the DLL and ProgID that points back to controlName.

Answer (score 1):

I have now got the Mappoint control working but in a slightly different way. The control does appear on the list of controls the test container can use. I have tried reregistering it and unregistering it but still it doesn't appear on the list of controls when I try a "Insert ActiveX Control". However if I use "Add/Remove Toolbox Items" I can add it to the toolbox and then drag it into my app where it works fine. I'm not sure why this method works but it does and I can get on with my coding.

Many thanks for all your help with this.